# Modifying object in this.state of a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a working code (context + toggler callback):

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleThemeToggle = this.handleThemeToggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        theme: ConsumerTestThemes.dark,
        toggler: this.handleThemeToggle
    };
}
handleThemeToggle() {
    this.setState(state => ({ theme: state.theme === ConsumerTestThemes.dark ? ConsumerTestThemes.light : ConsumerTestThemes.dark }));
}
```

But I don't like the idea to pass the entire state as a value to the context.Provider in the rendering phase, so I'd like to encapsulate the theme data like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleThemeToggle = this.handleThemeToggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        themeData: {
            theme: ConsumerTestThemes.dark,
            toggler: this.handleThemeToggle
        }
    };
}
handleThemeToggle() {
    this.setState(state => ({ themeData.theme: state.themeData.theme === ConsumerTestThemes.dark ? ConsumerTestThemes.light : ConsumerTestThemes.dark }));
}
```

Unfortunately, this writing is not valid for JS ("Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (at the point of "themeData.theme:")). Am I missing something?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for this:

```
handleThemeToggle() {
    this.setState(state => ({ 
      themeData: {
        ...state.themeData, 
        theme: state.themeData.theme === ConsumerTestThemes.dark ? ConsumerTestThemes.light : ConsumerTestThemes.dark 
      }
    }));
}
```

In Javascript you can't set a field on a nested object like this: `{ parent.child: value }`, you have to write it out fully: `{ parent: { child: value }}`

Comment: OK, I see, so the setState reconstruct the entire object and doesn't only update the desired values! Thank you See, I just understood it now thanks to you ^^'